# Why was Maya Sorian of 2050 dead but not Laura Shane of the same timeline?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-adam-project

In the movie The Adam Project, in 2018, the death of 2018's Maya Sorian kills the same of 2050's.

> [image: maya-death]

We see a scene of 2022, where Laura Shane was most possibly killed by Maya Sorian.

> [image: maya-shooting]

The dead body was not shown however, Maya Sorian of 2050 reveals it in 2018 scene in the site of the EM reactor.

> Ask your son how I play? I had to kill his wife twice to protect the integrity of my programme.

I believed that killing someone of a later age doesn't kill the one of a past age.

Until, Laura Shane was shown again in 2050 coming to the classroom where Adam starts befriending her.

How is it that Laura Shane was alive again in 2050 towards the end of the movie?

Comment: Laura at the end is *younger* than the one who (in the erased timeline) had any contact with Maya.  —By “kill his wife twice” I think Maya means: send her on a suicide mission and then, when she survived that, sho ot her in person.

Answer (score 1):

The Laura who was killed by Sorian was the 2050 Laura who had travelled back to 2022 and not the Laura who would have naturally existed in 2018.

As such, when the timeline is reset the 2018 Laura grows up as she would have done without the timeline being affected and now meets Adam as was previously described.

Comment: Do you mean in the final scene Adam (of 2018) meets Laura (of 2018)?

Comment: From Wikipedia `Years later, a much happier adult Adam meets Laura for the first time in a situation mirroring their first meeting in the original timeline.`. Also, seems from the conversation that he was aware of what happened. Is he not Adam of 2022?

Comment: Nope, he's the Adam from 2018 who apparently had a much better relationship with his father.